# fluidRow in shinydashboard sidebar swaps into body or is split into two rows

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to incorporate a `fluidRow` into the sidebar of a shinydashboard app. I would expect that by doing so I could split the width of the sidebar into 12 columns. What happens, however, is that only 10 or 11 columns are displayed in the sidebar while the remaining columns swap over into the dashboard body or are moved to the row below. For example, the code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      fluidRow(
        column(10, textInput("TextInput", "Text")),
        column(2, checkboxInput("CheckBox", "Check?"))
     )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

produces the layout (with resolution 1680 x 1050)

[image]

Using an 11-1 split the checkbox is moved to the row below

[image]

How can In ensure that a fluidRow in the sidebar will always stay inside the sidebar and in exactly one row?

Answer (score 1):

Will this do?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      fluidRow(
      div(style="display: inline-block; width: 62%;",textInput("TextInput", "Text")),
      div(style="display: inline-block; width: 4%;",checkboxInput("CheckBox", "Check?")))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Not really, since if you insert `textInput("TextInput1", "Text1"),` right before the fluidrow then the two `textInput` boxes appear misaligned. Basically I am looking for a solution that works on a batch basis and does not need to be checked and retuned for every case.